# Get pair of value from json file by sed

Tags: json, bash, sed

I want to get value from JSON file:
Example:

```
{"name":"ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail","value":"test@gmail.com"},{"name":"ghprbPullId","value":"226"},{"name":"ghprbTargetBranch","value":"master"},
```

My expect is : 
I want to get `test@gmail.com`, `226` and `master`.

Comment: a json parser would be the first choice...

Comment: would you make your answer clearly and  easy to understand?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with sed? You really should use a proper JSON parser.

Comment: Please add some example code showing what you've tried.  It's easier for us to help you if we have a starting point.  It would also be helpful if you let us know what libraries you are using and if there are any you can't use.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is the wrong tool for processing JSON.

Assuming you have a file `tmp.json` with *valid* JSON like

```
[{"name":"ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail","value":"test@gmail.com"}, 
 {"name":"ghprbPullId","value":"226"},
 {"name":"ghprbTargetBranch","value":"master"}]
```

you can use `jq '.[].value' tmp.son`.

If the file instead contains

```
{"name":"ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail","value":"test@gmail.com"}
{"name":"ghprbPullId","value":"226"}
{"name":"ghprbTargetBranch","value":"master"}
```

(i.e., just a stream of 3 separate JSON objects, you could use `jq '.value' tmp.json`, as `jq` will apply the filter to each object in succession. You can also use `jq -s '.[].value' tmp.son`, where the `-s` flag tells `jq` to read the entire input into an array first. This lets you use the same filter in both cases.

Comment: it means that i have to install jq to my machine, right?. I am using Redhat 6

Comment: Correct. But if you intend to work with JSON from the shell, you really should.

Comment: while I am finding way how o install jq to my Redhat, do you have any suggestion about sed or grep in this case? If i just want to get one entry test@gmail.com. can we use sed or grep to do it ?

Comment: I'm not even going to post it as an answer because it'll hardly work for any case but yours (and this it's just now how you should do it):  `cat test.json | grep -E '"value":".*?"'  -o | cut -d: -f2 | sed s/\"//g`

Comment: But @chepner is right, if not jq, you can use Python which should come preinstalled on your machine.

Comment: Thanks all. I will try to do it. BTW, @Sarnab,  can you provide python statement in this case?

Comment: @SArnab That's not right anyway; `*?` is only recognized as a non-greedy operator in Perl regexes, not extended regular extensions, to start.

Comment: @lppnghia A suggestion regarding `sed` or `grep` is you should never use those with json data.. Use a specialized tool like `jq` for that. Here is how to [\[ install \]](http://serverfault.com/a/768061) jq on Redhat6.. I don't think an *stock* rpm is available yet.. The method at link would be easier if you don't trust a third party repo

Comment: @chepner Huh, was  not aware of that. Sorry for the mistake. But it did work on my OSX machine for the quick test. http://imgur.com/GmQYuEP But regardless, I agree with your answer.

Comment: Yes, result of grep command is : test@gmail.com},{name  . Can you correct it ?

Comment: @lppnghia it really is not worth the trouble for anyone. With a properly formatted JSON document (yours is not, you must correct this first) you can parse out the values using simple accessors in `jq` or Python's json.tool

Comment: ok. Let me try it on. and update status later. Thanks all supporters